# In SlackTextViewController, if I present a UIAlertController, the text input view doesn't show properly

Tags: slacktextviewcontroller

I had an issue when using `SlackTextViewController` where based on tapping a chat item, I presented a `UIAlertController`. When I dismissed the UIAlertController, the text input control didn't reappear; the keyboard showed back up, but it covered the text input control. I had to manually dismiss the keyboard and show it again.

How do I get it to not cover the text input control when the keyboard reappears?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`SlackTextViewController` has a method of dealing with this, but it's not documented well. When the notification comes in to show the keyboard, the first responder is the `UIAlertController` so it basically ignores it. There's a function that controls whether to override this behavior:

```
- (BOOL)forceTextInputbarAdjustmentForResponder:(UIResponder *)responder
{
    return NO;
}
```

Basically in your subclass override this to be something that returns `true` if `responder` is a `UIAlertController`.